# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\CrudController] does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, require-once, laravel-10

I'm creating a project in laravel, i have created a controller, and when i try to bind it to the route, it throws an error not found.

CrudController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use PhpParser\Node\Stmt\TryCatch;

class CrudController extends Controller{
    public function index(){
        $datos=DB::select("select * from Empleados");
        return view("welcome")->with("datos", $datos);
    }

    public function create(Request $request){
        try {
            $sql=DB::insert("insert into Empleados(id,nombre,apellido_paterno,apellido_materno,direccion,telefono,correo)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?",[
                $request->id,
                $request->nombre,
                $request->apellido_paterno,
                $request->apellido_materno,
                $request->direccion,
                $request->telefono,
                $request->correo
            ]);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            $sql = 0;
        }
        if ($sql == true) {
            return back()->with("Correcto","Empleado registado correctamente");
        } else {
            return back()->with("Incorrecto","Empleado no se ha registado correctamente");
        }

    }
}
```

Web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

// Route::get('/', function () {
//     return view('welcome');
// });

Route::get('/',[CrudController::class, 'index'])->name('crud.index');

// Ruta para agregar un nuevo empleado
Route::post('/agregar_empleado',[CrudController::class, 'create'])->name('crud.create');
```

[Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6D2D.png)

I tried solutions on web but none it worked for me.
Does anyone have an idea of the problem?

Comment: Have you tried composer dump-autoload or clear the cache ? Look the name of file CrudController.php is the same that the name of your class CrudController ?

Comment: Is CRUDCONTROLLER.PHP file named like this (all capitals)? If so, considering you put the file in the correct directory, this is your problem. For PSR-4 autoloading (which Laravel uses by default), the file MUST be named exactly like the class name. In this case: CrudController.php